# How do I propagate onClick from parent link to nested spans?

Tags: reactjs

I have buttons that I'd like each line within which to have different styling, and I want to be able to add a class so the user knows which button they selected. I'd like the class to be added regardless of where I click on the button, but it's only being added when I click on the background. No style is added if I happen to click the text of the button, which is in spans. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
<a href="#" role="button" onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let el = e.target;
        setAgeSelection('0-3');
        el.classList.toggle('selected');
    }} className="btn-resume btn-resume-large btn-resume-blue">
    <span className="txt-36px bold-txt">0-3 years</span><br />
    <span className="txt-22px italic-txt">Career explorer</span>
</a>
```

And here it is in codepen:
https://codepen.io/ybilal253/pen/GRNdLzw

Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, provide a working example, because code you sent should work.
Maybe there is additional styles on your spans with something like `pointer-events: none` which prevent any user interactions...

Comment: I posted it on codepen. When I click on the background, the checkmark appears as intended. But when I click on the text, it doesn't. No pointer-events on any of the classes. https://codepen.io/ybilal253/pen/GRNdLzw